# Create a trigger TR1 for INSERT, DELETE triggering event where trigger should be fired if the transactions are performed on SUNDAY

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Alter trigger TR1
on Employee 
Instead of Insert,Delete
as
begin
    if (datepart(dw,getdate())=1)

    Raiserror('cannot insert records since today is sunday',16,1)
end

insert into Employee values (5,'sara',9890980)

select * from Employee
```

I write this code it is working fine but 
records are not inserted into the table if it is not sunday
and if it is sunday the records is not inserted its giving error.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: An `instead of` trigger is one where *you're* promising to perform the actions required (rather than an `after` trigger where you let the DB do its normal job and then inspect the data)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this
You have to add normal DML commands

```
alter trigger TR1
on Employee 
Instead of Insert,Delete
as
begin
    if (datepart(dw,getdate())=1)
        Raiserror('cannot insert records since today is sunday',16,1)
    else
    begin
        insert into Employee select * from inserted
        delete from Employee where id in (select id from deleted)
    end
end

go
```

Comment: @KrishnaM if it's working, then please make sure you mark it as the answer. This will also help others if they have the same, or similar, question in the future.

Comment: Please note that the requested trigger does not work for Instead of Update. If UPDATE was also requested, we should add an other section for UPDATE cases joining deleted and inserted tables on PK fields